# Map an array into another array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of dict like:

```
[{'id': 1, 'tags': ['tag_a', 'tag_b']}, {'id': 2, 'tags': ['tag_c', 'tag_b']}]
```

and I would like to convert this array into a new array based on `ticket_id` and each `tag` value should be an object in the array.

I almost did it using the following function:

```
raw = [{'id': 1, 'tags': ['tag_a', 'tag_b']}, {'id': 2, 'tags': ['tag_c', 'tag_b']}]

def transform(ticket):
    result = []
    for tag in ticket.get('tags', []):
        result.append({'ticket_id': ticket.get('id'), 'tag': tag, 'sync': '123'})
    return result

print(list(map(transform, raw)))
```

But it's returning something like `[[{...}], [{...}]]` and the syntax looks strange.

What is the right approach to return something like:

```
[{'ticket_id': 1, 'tag': 'tag_a', 'sync': '123'}, {'ticket_id': 1, 'tag': 'tag_b', 'sync': '123'}, ...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to flatten your results. Essentially, you used a map operation when you wanted a flat-map operation.

You can do this in one go by using a nested list comprehension:

```
[x for ticket in raw for x in transform(ticket)]
```

Of course, you could have done something like:

```
[x for xs in map(transform, raw) for x in xs]
```

Or just a regular nested loop would work.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it using nested for loops. Moreover, you don't need to `map` your function. You can just pass the list to the function and print. The problem with your code was that you were using a single for loop whereas, the depth (length) of your `tags` was more than one

```
raw = [{'id': 1, 'tags': ['tag_a', 'tag_b']}, {'id': 2, 'tags': ['tag_c', 'tag_b']}]

def transform(ticket):
    result = []
    for dic in raw:
        for tag in dic['tags']:
            result.append({'ticket_id': dic['id'], 'tag': tag, 'sync': '123'})
    return result

print(transform(raw))
# [{'ticket_id': 1, 'tag': 'tag_a', 'sync': '123'}, {'ticket_id': 1, 'tag': 'tag_b', 'sync': '123'}, 
#  {'ticket_id': 2, 'tag': 'tag_c', 'sync': '123'}, {'ticket_id': 2, 'tag': 'tag_b', 'sync': '123'}]
```